# How to master Sri Vidya Sadhana

Tags: meditation

What practices shall be followed to master Sri Vidya Sadhana?
What does each mantra of Sri Vidya Sadhana mean? I've taken Sri Vidya Deeksha from a Guru, I want to understand the meaning of each mantra, to have the emotion while I recite the matra.

Comment: If you have Guru, then the question is best answered by him. Besides, mantras work even if you don't know the meaning. When you touch a very hot object, it will burn you whether you know beforehand it is hot or not. Mantras are vibrations, their vibrations will work on you whether you know the meaning or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What practices shall be followed to master Sri Vidya Sadhana? What
>   does each mantra of Sri Vidya Sadhana mean? I've taken Sri Vidya
>   Deeksha from a Guru,

Once you have taken Deeksha the only person capable of answering your questions is your Guru itself. We are no one here. More so since all your questions are related to the Sadhana into which you are being initiated.

> I want to understand the meaning of each mantra, to have the emotion
>   while I recite the mantra.

This is important. You should learn the meaning of the mantra from your Guru.

See the following verses and you will know why knowing the meaning of mantras is important.

> **MantrArtham** Mantrachaitanyam YonimudrAm **na Vetti Yah**||
>
> **SatakotijapenApi Tasya Siddhirna JAyate** ||
>
> **Those who do mantra japa without knowing its meaning** and consciousness and without knowing the Yonimudra ,**for them even
>   crores of japa can't bring mantra siddhi.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram,Chapter 15,Verse 60.**

The yonimudra part in the verse is of course irrelevant to your question but knowing the meaning of mantra is important.

In some other text, those who do mantra japa without realizing its meaning , **are compared to the donkeys which carry loads of sugar** .

And another relevant verse is the following :

> TannisthaTathgataPrAnastaChittastathparAyanah ||
>
> TathPadArthAnusandhAnam Kurban Mantram Japeth Priye||
>
> Priye,mantra japa should be done with unflinching concentration and
>   **constantly  meditating upon the meaning of the mantra in mind.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram,Chapter 15,Verse 114.**

Answer (score 2):

Always a sadhak requires a Guru. Without a guru, it is almost impossible as he guides you.

Since you have already taken a deeksha from a Guru, is it not better to find the meanings of those mantras from the same guru?
Because a word has many meanings and he will explain with a meaning which will suit your attitude and temper better.

Still for information on Sri Vidya, you can refer these websites
1) http://srividyasadhana.com/ 
2) Audio's on Sri Vidya by SriM